# FluentNHibernate automapping ManyToMany

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, automapping

I'm trying to map a many-to-many relation, but the mapping doesn't work (list property stays null and items are not stored.

I use the following tables:

```
User(Id, Name, Password,...)
Role(Id, Name)
RoleUser(UserId, RoleId) with a compound primary key
```

My entity files are

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
public class Role
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual IList<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

There are two conventions that are applied:

```
public class MyForeignKeyConvention : ForeignKeyConvention
{
    protected override string GetKeyName(Member property, Type type)
    {
        return property == null ? type.Name + "Id" : property.Name + "Id";
    }
}
public class MyManyToManyConvention : IHasManyToManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IManyToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        var firstName = instance.EntityType.Name;
        var secondName = instance.ChildType.Name;

        if (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(firstName, secondName) > 0)
        {
            instance.Table(string.Format("{0}{1}", secondName, firstName));
            instance.Inverse();
        }
        else
        {
            instance.Table(string.Format("{0}{1}", firstName, secondName));
            instance.Not.Inverse();
        }

        instance.Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

When I export the mappings to files, i get the following snippet within user definition as an example:

```
<id name="Id" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
  <column name="Id" />
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
<bag cascade="all" inverse="true" name="Roles" table="RoleUser">
  <key>
    <column name="UserId" />
    <column name="UserId" />
  </key>
  <many-to-many class="Security.Role, Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"&gt;
    <column name="RoleId" />
  </many-to-many>
</bag>
<property name="UserName" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
  <column name="UserName" />
</property>
```

The duplicate column UserId within the key seems not correct to me.
I'm not sure what I made wrong. Thanks for help.

Comment: does schemaexport generate the right schema? you can export the ddl into a file instead of the db

Comment: The schema export snippet was generated by method ExportTo(folder).
What do you mean?

Comment: you posted the generated mappings but i would like to see the `new SchemExport(config).Execute(new StreamWriter("somefile.txt").WriteLine, false, null, false)`

Comment: Thanks Firo. This hint is very useful. The problem was the schema of the mapping table.
I ended up with a custom ManyToManyTableConvention.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the schema of the mapping table. I ended up with a custom ManyToManyTableConvention.